# Visualization of Geographical information on mobile devices

Tags: development, mobile

To complete my thesis i have to develop mobile GIS application which will test/handle some issue related to visualization presentation of geographical/spatial information on mobile devices.

I will test the application usability in lab(desktop environment)and application should contain two ,three data layers belong to one specific domain

Where to start , which is best tool to develop such application prototype, how will i test usability concerns with that application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which mobile device are you supposed to use?

Answer (score 3):

I had much the same requirement for my undergrad dissertation, and I decided to go with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) to minimise the programming required for my mobile device (an HTC Desire running Android). All it took on the mobile side was an app with a browser window that opened up the site with my GIS data on it, so it wouldn't be a very hard to create say an iPhone application with the same look and feel.

OpenLayers supports mobile browsing fairly well, and can deal with WFS-T if you need to edit data on your device.

Of course, you will need a server to connect to, but for initial testing I just set up a linux virtual machine on my development PC running [mapserver](http://mapserver.org/) and [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), then I used a cloud hosting service for when I wanted to test it in the field. This meant it was fairly painless to transfer the configuration I had on my local VM to the cloud VM because both of them were headless (i.e. no GUI) Ubuntu JeOS distros.

Comment: (+1) An alternative to mapserver would be to run GeoServer. My personal preference.

Comment: Indeed. It is easier to set up with its web-based frontend, and supports WFS-T, whereas you need tinyows with MapServer. GeoServer does require Apache and Tomcat (or similar) which can bloat an installation, but for a thesis this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at gvSIG - http://www.gvsig.org They have a gvSIG mobile product which seems quite good (never had a play though). Its open-source and Java based.